# subkey: command not found error

Tags: substrate-node-template, subkey, command

I installed subkey by following instructions

[`https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/`](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/)

and `./target/release/subkey --help` command is working fine but any other subkey commands are not working and giving command not found error how to fix it?

[image: subkey:command not found error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./target/release/subkey --version` try this

Answer (score 1):

You have just built the binary locally and it is available only by the direct call to it (`./target/release/subkey`). If you want to use it as a command/alias (just `subkey`) you have to either create an shell alias or add the path to this binary to the $PATH env

Comment: how to add subkey binary to $PATH env?

Comment: here are some ways of doing this in linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path